# Angular Universal server rendering WebSocket

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io, angular-universal

Are there any examples of Angular Universal with WebSockets?

Serverside rendering does not know wat a WebSocket object is in my case. And if I use socket.io the node server hangs when trying to make a connections.

Some additional information about the problem:

I downloaded angular-universal-starter from github: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter
Which works fine out of the box running 'npm install' and 'npm start'

But after i added the following code to AppComponent

```
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
       ngOnInit() {
           let webSocket = new WebSocket("----server url----")
       }
   }
```

I got the following error in my NodeJs server console:

```
EXCEPTION: WebSocket is not defined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined
    at AppComponent.ngOnInit (/Volumes/Development/cacadu/website/universal-starter-master2/dist
/server/index.js:41725:29)
```

Comment: Can you show some example code of what you have now, and post some errors / debugging information that might be coming out?

Comment: See my comment below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try only calling the websocket on the Client, for example you can detect whether it's the browser or the server with these imports

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
```

Then use them inside your code, this might be able to fix the problem!

```
@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    private isBrowser: boolean = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);

    constructor(
       @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
    ) {
        if (isBrowser) {
            let webSocket = new WebSocket("----server url----");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had tried import { isBrowser, isNode } from 'angular2-universal/browser'; But of course that is wrong... Things seem to work now!

Comment: what if I want to call it on the server as well? what if I want to use some websocket data for ssr rendering?

Comment: You'd need to use DI in that case to have a node websocket implementation just for SSR and make sure you disconnect it right when the server has rendered your application to a string, and then reconnect on the Browser side. @Ronin

Comment: Also I updated the answer to use the latest platform-server imports needed, angular2-universal has long since been deprecated

Comment: Fine. You saved me after trying to fix that issue for two days. Your are legend

Comment: how do you know this and is this still a thing?

Comment: my issue is the angular universal server. I can't get it to run.

Comment: @MarkPieszak-Trilon.io can you explain why this works and not using ngzone.runOutsideAngular() <<< ?