# "ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined" when using RxJs WebSocketSubject and Angular Universal

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, angular-universal

I'm setting up an [angular 6.x univeral project](https://angular.io/guide/universal) in order to leverage its SSR (Server-Side Rendering) capabilities. In my app, I'm using websocket communication using RxJs.

More specifically, I'm, using `WebSocketSubject` and `webSocket` in my angular universal 6.x project, which works fine on the browser platform. However, when running the node web server (that contains the SSR stuff (Server-Side Rendering)), an error is thrown:

> ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined

**Example code:**

```
// not actually code from the reproduction repo
import { WebSocketSubject, webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

const socket: WebSocketSubject<any> = webSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');
socket.subscribe(msg => doSomething(msg));
```

Please note, that **the error doesn't occur on the browser version** of the app (i.e. `ng serve` won't throw the error), but only after compiling the SSR stuff and running the express web server. To reproduce the error, the builds have to be run first:

```
# install dependencies
npm install

# build angular bundles for browser and server platforms
npm run build:client-and-server-bundles

# build the webserver
npm run webpack:server

# start the webserver
npm run serve:ssr

# the app is now being served at http://localhost:8081/
# open it in the browser and the error will occur: 'ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined'
```

I've also set up a [reproduction repo](https://github.com/takahser/angular-universal-ssr-with-rxjs-websocket).

**Environment I'm using:**

- Runtime: Angular 6
- RxJS version: 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2 (tested all)

## Edit 2018-08-02

I was able to address the problem more accurately. It seems, that this is also a webpack problem. Angular Universal creates a js bundle for running the angular app on the node server, but there is natively no websocket implementation on Node. Therefore, it has to be added manually as a dependency (npm package). I tried adding it to the js server bundle (`const WebSocket = require('ws');` manually, *which resolves the problem* (i.e. ReferenceError disappears). However, when I add it to the TypeScript code that gets transcompiled into the js bundle later on, it won't work.

**Further details**

- The webpack loader `ts-loader` is used for compiling TypeScript => JavaScript
- The websocket depedency was added to the package.json: `"ws": "^6.0.0"`
- Attempting to reference the ws dependency by adding `const WebSocket = require('ws');` to the **uncompiled TypeScript code won't resolve the issue**. It would get compiled into `var WebSocket = __webpack_require__(333);` in the js output file, the dependency won't be able to be resolved.
- **Manually** changing `var WebSocket = __webpack_require__(333);` => `const WebSocket = require('ws');` in the compiled js file **would resolve the issue**, but of course it's a hack.

**So, the questions are:**

- Can I "force" webpack to compile the dependency `const WebSocket = require('ws');` => `const WebSocket = require('ws');` (no changes)?
- Or, would it might be a better solution, to register this dependency in the angular universal npm package and create a pull request?

Comment: Is it not a matter of checking if you are server side or client side in your code, so that you using use sockets when the code is executed in the browser?

Comment: @David There is a similar question on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700412/angular-universal-server-rendering-websocket), that suggests to only call the websocket on the client, which makes the error disappear, however, it's not a solution for me. I really want to use the websocket even when the code is executed on the server.

Comment: That's what I meant. Since the code is executed server side then client side, why do you need to use websockets server side?

Comment: @David so it gets included in the server-side rendered page as well. If I make a http request to any route in my angular app, I'd like to get the full markup for that specific route, so it should contain even websocket data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All it takes is this:

```
// set WebSocket on global object
(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');
```

And of course, we need the `ws` dependency as well in the package.json:

`npm i ws -s`

Comment: Hi i am using angular 7 and I want to use it with http not with ws or wss how do i accomplish it.

Comment: This feels hacky, but it works. Better way?

Answer (score 7):

The RxJS webSocket function can receive a WebSocket Constructor as an argument. This can be used to run webSocket in a non-browser/universal environment like this.

```
const WebSocketConstructor = WebSocket || require('ws')

const socket: WebSocketSubject<any> = webSocket({
    url: 'wss://echo.websocket.org', 
    WebSocketCtor: WebSocketConstructor,
});


// OR...

import { WebSocket, ...otherStuff... } from 'ws';
import { webSocket, ...otherStuff... } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

const socket$ = webSocket({
  url: 'wss://someplace.com',
  WebSocketCtor: WebSocket,
});
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. That one feels hacky, but this seems legit. Basic dev opinion. Both work...

Answer (score 2):

In nodeJS apps with ES6 or similar, you must use this:

> global.WebSocket = require('ws')

For example:

```
import { WebSocketSubject, webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

global.WebSocket = require('ws'); // <-- FIX ALL ERRORS
const subject = webSocket('ws://...');
```

No more errors.

My first answer!! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

in angular 17 is working like

```
import { WebSocketSubject, webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

const socket: WebSocketSubject<any> = webSocket({
    url: 'wss://localhost:7039/ws'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a npm package using websockets.
To provide compatibility for server side js and browser js i use this code.

(Note: it is typescript)

```js
if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    (global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');
}
```

Like you mentioned, the browser already has a WebSocket in its global object `window` but node does not.
Since the browser does not have `global`, this simple check works well.

Compiled code:

```
if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    global.WebSocket = require('ws');
}
```