# angular universal + socket.io, how to properly wait for browser side?

Tags: socket.io, angular7, server-side-rendering

I found topic like: [Angular Universal server rendering WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700412/angular-universal-server-rendering-websocket)

And it is correct that I should use any code with wrapper like if (isBrowserSide)...

What is my problem that while initializing components I cannot figure out how to properly wait for that moment where browser side is available.

I have tried something like:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    if (isBrowserSide) {
        // do some code on window (bind events etc)
    }
}, 2000)
```

with this one the problem is that it still doesnt see the window/browser side even site is rendered and for example delay is bigger

other tries:

```
setInterval(() => {
    if(isBrowserSide) {
        // do some code
    }
}, 3000)
```

in that case the side is never loaded (im getting the same result with setTimeout and recursion function and boolean in order to finish but it looks like i cant finish SSR with that way so it is infinite loop).

So please help me, how can I set my code to finish SSR and then if it is a browser side bind any events to window

Comment: Looks like ngAfterContentInit and ngAfterViewInit in any component responding always with true (isBrowserSide), any ideas about using setTimeout etc? if not i will have to use that hook

Comment: so weird... even my component see that isBrowserSide, when I want to reassign rooms in that socket service isBrowserSide is still false... I hate SSR blah... Any one was struggling with similar problem?

Comment: have you find any solution to solve this?